# Things board Cassandra compitablity

Tags: cassandra, thingsboard

Does Thingsboard is compatible with Cassandra 4 ? Please share if there any documentation

Answer (score 0):

The recommended version is DataStax community 3.0.9

[Thingsboard Doc](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/windows/?ubuntuThingsboardDatabase=hybrid)